# Xcode 8's "Insert Newline and Leave Selection Before It" shortcut not working

Tags: xcode, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Xcode 8.3.2 as of this moment and was trying to use the default shortcut "Control-O" to perform a "Insert Newline and Leave Selection Before It" in the code editor.

Supposedly, according to Apple's official documentation of the keyboard shortcut "Control-O" at [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201236) where it is also described as "Insert a new line after the insertion point", which should perform the equivalent of pressing enter and up.

However, under default settings, Xcode only does a regular carriage return and leaves the cursor at one space before the standard 4-space tab. This shortcut works fine in most other Mac applications like its own notes app.

Inside Xcode, I tried setting manually the "Insert Newline and Leave Selection Before It" to other key combinations, but none of them have any effect, even the original Control-O.

I was wondering if there is a way to make this handy shortcut work in Xcode. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check your key bindings in Xcode : `Preferences` > `Key Bindings` > search for `Insert newline and leave`, and see if there's a ⚠️. The behavior works for me in Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002).

Comment: There is no ⚠️  at where you have described.